# EWS Managed - Is it possible to get full "From" details using "FindItems"?

Tags: exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api

I'm using the Exchange Web Services Managed API to search a message folder using `FindItems`. The code I'm using is this:

```
var search = new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(
    ItemSchema.Subject,
    "subject I want");

ItemView searchView = new ItemView(9999);
searchView.PropertySet = new PropertySet(
   BasePropertySet.IdOnly,
   ItemSchema.Subject,
   ItemSchema.DateTimeReceived,
   EmailMessageSchema.From);
searchView.OrderBy.Add(
   ItemSchema.DateTimeReceived,
   SortDirection.Descending);
searchView.Traversal = ItemTraversal.Shallow;

var searchResults = _service.FindItems(
   folderToSearch.Id,
   search,
   searchView);
```

The search works fine, and the properties I've specified in the `searchView.PropertySet` do get returned. The problem is that it doesn't return **all** of the details of `From`.

I iterate `searchResults`, and cast the items to type `EmailMessage` or `PostItem` as appropriate, to access the `From` property, which returns an `EmailAddress` object. On that object, the `Name` property is set, but `Address` is null.

If I then **bind** the item, like:

```
var boundItem = Item.Bind(_service, message.Id);
var boundItemEmail = boundItem as EmailMessage;
```

Then `boundItemEmail.From.Address` is *not* null, it returns the senders email address.

The trouble is, binding a message can be a rather time-consuming process, compared to the much faster `FindItems` operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the [LoadPropertiesForItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.exchangeservice.loadpropertiesforitems(v=exchg.80).aspx) method to get the From property, it's faster than binding to individual messages.

Comment: At first I thought that wouldn't really help, since `LoadPropertiesForItems` requires a `PropertySet` parameter, just like I'm passing to `FindItems`. But strangely enough, it **does** load the full set of `From` properties, despite `FindItems` only loading a sub-set. -  `_service.LoadPropertiesForItems(searchResults, new PropertySet(EmailMessageSchema.From));`